# How To get Post Order by time get_terms in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, filtering

I want to ordery my post time means latest post will be seen first ,
my code is here ,

```
  <?php
        $all_terms=get_terms('filtering_category', 
          array(
          'hide_empty' => false,
          'orderby' => 'count',

            ));
```

this order by count is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting order by date, you can use 'post_date' in order by.

So your code will be modified something like below :-

```
<?php
    $all_terms=get_terms('filtering_category', 
      array(
      'hide_empty' => false,
      'orderby' => 'post_date',

        ));
```

Please refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters for detailed Order and OrderBy information.

Let me know if you need my help further....